# Post Build Event is called before the builds completes RAD studio XE4

Tags: c++builder, post-build-event, c++builder-xe4

I am new to RAD studio XE4 IDE, I just wanted to run a vbs file after the build by using post build event command field in project options.

The problem is, the vb script file is executing every time a file is compiled in project although the expected behavior is it should be called after the complete build of whole project. although the same was working fine in Embarcadero RAD studio 2010

following is the command i put in post build event command field:

```
cscript _zApply.vbs $(OUTPUTFILENAME)
```

In Embarcadero RAD studio 2010 i used this command in same field (it is working fine while the above one failed):

```
cscript _zApply.vbs Example.exe
```

Comment: i tried but no success :(

Comment: Please define what you mean by "every time a file is compiled"

Comment: By "every time a file is compiled" do you mean that you're doing a build or make, and the post-build event is called for every .cpp file that's in the project (ie as the build dialog shows a file, the script is called too?)

Comment: when I build All to build the project the script is called before builds and linking completes so it seems that scripts is being called for every .cpp file that is being compiled instead of waiting for whole proj to compile.

Comment: Are you observing the post build action being executed multiple times? Because that's what you seem to be claiming. How can we reproduce this? And finally, I removed the Delphi tags because you are not using Delphi.

Comment: Do you have post-build options set for each individual file? Right-click a .cpp file for which you see the build event occur, and click 'Edit Local Options'. Are there any post-build events? If I do that, your script gets called with the resulting .obj filename. Apart from that, I can't reproduce this in a new XE4 project, trying various combinations of compiler settings, background compilation, out-of-process compilation, and even injected headers in case that caused something. You will need to provide us much more information please.

Comment: (Continuing) - Can you reproduce this with a new XE4 project? If so, *please give exact steps for creating that new project.* (As you can see I tried many things and couldn't reproduce, so if you can we need to know how.) If not, what is the difference between your new and old projects? Opening the .cbproj files and comparing may help - a diff will show too many things, but manually examine likely-looking settings and the post-build areas of each project.

Comment: Is your project new, or has it just started displaying these symptoms, or is it upgraded from an old version, or...? (Typically you should always create a new project when upgrading IDEs - it's a pain but unfortunately necessary since options don't always get upgraded properly. Plus, if this doesn't happen in a new project, you've found your solution!) Basically all my questions could be summed up as 'please give a lot more pertinent information' :)

Comment: @KenWhite No worries, but I'm only guessing what the OP means. It's an educated guess though.

Comment: @user3920690 Any feedback? Did you solve the problem? Can you provide the extra info we asked for? Don't leave us hanging!